# How to know which public key was used when someone used passwordless ssh login?

Tags: logs, sshd, openssh, key-authentication

Say for some reason, there is only a "user" account on a `shhd` server. Everyone has his own private key to `ssh` to the server, as "user".

Then, is there a way to see who is he (during or after his session)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see which SSH public key was used in the syslog.

The authentication subset of the syslog is usually at `/var/log/auth.log`. For the whole syslog, you can try `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`.

The log lines should look something like this:

> Sep 10 19:17:00 server.example.com sshd[1337]: Accepted publickey for ansible from 127.0.0.1 port 59934 ssh2: RSA 5a:5d:18:5d:21:b4:e3:f3:8a:ec:c3:d6:93:99:87:ae

You should be able to parse this log with a tool like [logstash](http://logstash.net/) to build real statistics.

Comment: This is probably the best way, but there is nothing stopping users from exchanging keys with each other.  Users can add new keys to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  So you probably want to also secure authorized_keys as suggested in the other answer.